# OpenCV Ip Camera Image Deterioration

Tags: opencv, ip-camera

I have successfully connected with a IP camera using OpenCV. If I just show the image using imshow, then it's all fine... But if I try to do some CPU processing with the image (I equalize the image and run a face detector...), the image starts to deteriorate (I keep getting ac-tex damaged in the console)... Is starts to blur and blur and blur... I dont know why this is happening. I can confirm that this does not happen when getting images from my iSight camera (I am running on a iMac...) Besides that, I am having a really weird time with OpenCV. The face detection doesn't seem to work when I run the app in Release mode. I am on Windows 8 and using VS 2010.

Can someone shed some light at these problems?

Comment: I suggest you break up your question into more detailed parts and post some code (unless this is an April Fool's joke...).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you break up your problem into small parts. Some questions that I have for you:

- The image capture and presentation are working without any processing?
- A local camera with the face detector algorithm is working?
- You said about release mode, it means that is working on the debug version?

Comment: Hi Malf! Sorry for taking so long to answer the questions you made. a) Yes. b) Yes. c) It doesn't work in either modes but it works in both modes as longs as i don't make any processing with the image.